# Checking HDD SMART Data from Live USB

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to use a Ubuntu 18.04.2 Live USB to check SMART Data on hard drives but it asks me for the Live Session User password.  I do not have persistence enabled and would prefer not to create a new account although this may not be possible.

Does anyone know how I can authenticate to check the SMART Data or is there not a way to do this without persistence enabled on the USB and making a new admin account?  I just want to boot from this Live USB and do a short check of the SMART Data quickly

I appreciate any help I can get with this and thank you in advance.

Comment: It should take less than a minute to create a new Administrator account on a persistent USB, but have you checked if a blank password works for you as Live Session User? (This does not always work for me).

Comment: Thanks for the input, C.S. Cameron.  I will use your suggestion to add an admin account as the password is not blank.